# Is ClearChat end-to-end encryption and user authentication secure?

Tags: encryption, authentication, instant-messaging

ClearChat is marketing itself as a secure alternative to messaging and collaborative work services like Slack, for use by businesses. Their security marketing (e.g. https://clearchat.com/compare) is based on two main claims:

1. That they use end-to-end encryption, meaning that they never have access to user data.
2. That they use user authentication, which is safer than password based security.

Are these claims accurate?

Comment: there are hundreds of such messengers, who make such claim, hardly any of them backs them with solid evidence. so be careful, avoid them

Comment: You'll find this interesting. ClearChat has open sourced it's encryption code. https://clearchat.com/blog/clearchat-open-sources-encryption-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find any source code of the tool on this site nor do I find any results from independent audits or any kind of common criteria or similar certificates. Essentially only their claims are on this site without any proof or independent test.

> Are these claims accurate?

It is impossible to tell. These claims might be true or might be not. It might be that they believe they are true but that independent test would find security problems. It might also that they knowingly tell lies. It is the equivalent of some stranger telling you to blindly trust him. Would you do it?

Comment: Thanks. Do you haopen to know of any open source Slack alternatives that do have end to end encryption?

Comment: @R.Duke: no I don't and product recommendations are off-topic here anyway.